# Merge two dataframes and create new features based on aggregations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, aggregation

I have two dataframes df_cust (customer data, approx. 250k rows) and df_trx (transactions, approx. 14mio rows). I would like to create new features in df_cust based on aggregations in df_trx (sum, max, min). Also I am trying to create new dummy features if customer has purchased item A, B or C.

Merging the two dataframes is no problem but I'm at a loss how to create the new features.

Highly appreciate any helpful suggestions

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

df_cust = pd.DataFrame({'CUST_ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                    'GENDER':  [1, 0, 0, 0]})

df_trx = pd.DataFrame({'CUST_ID': [1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1],
                   'AMOUNT':  [16, 89, 240, 20, 1303, 39, 2],
                   'DATE': ['2018-12-06', '2018-12-12', '2019-04-06', '2018-10-23', '2018-12-06', '2019-05-09', '2019-05-29'],
                   'ITEM': ['A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A']})
```

Expected result:

```
df_cust_merged = pd.DataFrame({'CUST_ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                           'GENDER':  [1, 0, 0, 0],
                           'AMOUNT_SUM': [18, 1323, 'NaN', 368],
                           'AMOUNT_MAX': [16, 1303, 'NaN', 240],
                           'AMOUNT_MIN': [2, 20, 'NaN', 39],
                           'FIRST_TRX': ['2018-12-06', '2018-10-23', 'NaN', '2018-12-12'],
                           'LAST_TRX': ['2019-05-29', '2018-12-06', 'NaN', '2019-05-09'],
                           'HAS_ITEM_A': [1, 1, 0, 1],
                           'HAS_ITEM_B': [0, 1, 0, 0],
                           'HAS_ITEM_C': [0, 0, 0, 1]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we do an `outer merge` to get the data together.

Then we `GroupBy.agg` with multiple functions: `mean`, `sum`, `max`, `min`, `first`, `last`.

Then we use `pd.crosstab` to get your `HAS_ITEM` columns (basically one-hot-encoding).

```
mrg1 = df_cust.merge(df_trx, on='CUST_ID', how='outer')

mrg = mrg1.groupby('CUST_ID').agg({'GENDER':'mean',
                                   'AMOUNT':['sum', 'max', 'min'],
                                   'DATE':['first', 'last']})

mrg.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in mrg.columns]

mrg = mrg.join(pd.crosstab(mrg1['CUST_ID'], mrg1['ITEM'], dropna=False).add_prefix('HAS_ITEM_')).reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
   CUST_ID  GENDER_mean  AMOUNT_sum  AMOUNT_max  AMOUNT_min  DATE_first   DATE_last  HAS_ITEM_A  HAS_ITEM_B  HAS_ITEM_C
0        1            1        18.0        16.0         2.0  2018-12-06  2019-05-29         2.0         0.0         0.0
1        2            0      1323.0      1303.0        20.0  2018-10-23  2018-12-06         1.0         1.0         0.0
2        3            0         0.0         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
3        4            0       368.0       240.0        39.0  2018-12-12  2019-05-09         1.0         0.0         2.0
```

Comment: Thanks Erfan, works like a charm. For the HAS_ITEM columns I was thinking about 1 or 0 (one-hot-encoding) but maybe count works good too. I will see what delivers the best result.